# How can i record each keyboard input in text file?

Tags: java, keyboard, awt, bufferedreader, keylistener

I would like to record every keyboard inputs into text file without using  **keyListener** How can I achieve this?

Comment: What environment? Coal, AWT, Swing...?

Comment: *"without using keyListener"*  Why without?

Comment: Because i need to keep every thing the user writes on the Pc

Answer (score 0):

Could try:

```
writeText() {
  Scanner Input = new Scanner(Systen.in);  
  System.out.println("enter a string: "); 
  String input = input.next();
  File theFile = new File("thisfile.txt");
  bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("thisfile.txt",true));
  bw.write(input);
}
```